# Laravel and Guzzle HTTP '406 Not Acceptable'

Tags: php, laravel, get, guzzle, http-status-code-406

I'm having an issue with Laravel and Guzzle. When ever I try this line of code with my external website 'violapractice.com' I get an error:

```
$res = $client->request('GET','http://violapractice.com/articles.json.php');
```

`` Client error: `GET http://violapractice.com/articles.json.php` resulted in a `406 Not Acceptable` response: <html><head><title>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</title><head><body><h1>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</h1><p>Generally a 406 e (truncated...) ``

I've tried requesting a none php file and get the same error:

```
$res = $client->request('GET','http://violapractice.com/test.html');
```

The odd thing is, if I use any other URL, like `https://stackoverflow.com` the GET request goes through with no issue.

Also, I tired using postman on `http://violapractice.com/articles.json.php` and it worked fine.

I've never experienced anything like this before. Ideas anyone?

Comment: May be they detect that you're not using a browser (with valid User-Agent) and block the request? Try to put a browser User-Agent in the headers.

Comment: They have Mod Security, which is blocking requests depending on some internal rules, which we don't know. Normal browser request works, so try to mock the same request with the same headers as a normal browser and it should be working.

Comment: What user agent would you suggest using instead of 'User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.68.0 PHP/7.4.3'. Firefox?

Comment: Take one from a browser of your choice. Try to mimic the browser headers.

Comment: I tried `$client->setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0');` and got this: `cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: Mozilla (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

Comment: I just attempted to load `http://violapractice.com/articles.json.php` n my browser and got an error stating "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 6 column 1 of the JSON data" so I guess the returned data is not being served correctly.

Comment: It's because it's not valid JSON syntax until I run it through my back end code. Has nothing to do with the issue. Issue is solved by the way, read the post below.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I ended up turning off ModSecurity in the violapractice.com cpanel. I felt that the risk in doing this was minimal because the website is only accessible through admin login and has many layers of security.